# How to set ownership of exFAT drive when mounting?

Tags: mount, raspberrypi, exfat

There are a number of threads on this topic, but I have tried every single answer/suggestion and still have had no luck. Up until a few weeks ago, my mount command worked as expected, which almost makes me think this is some sort of bug.

I have a Raspberry Pi, running the 64-bit OS:

`Linux raspberrypi 5.15.61-v8+ #1579 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 26 11:16:44 BST 2022 aarch64`

I have run the following command to install the required exFAT tools:

`sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

I have initialized a mount point with:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/fhpro`

**My desired behavior is that the drive is able to be read and written to by members of a certain group.** I understand I need to set ownership of the drive to the group when mounting it, as exFAT does not allow for file-specific permissions.

I have run the following commands to change ownership of the mount point itself:

```
sudo chown myusername /mnt/fhpro
sudo chgrp groupname /mnt/fhpro
```

I then mount the drive with the following command:

`sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sda1 /mnt/fhpro -o uid=1001,gid=1003,rw,fmask=0002,dmask=0002`

where `1001` and `1003` are the IDs of the desired user and group.

The command runs without error, and I am able to view the contents of the drive. However, the drive is owned by the `pi` user and group, not the user and group that were set. When I run `ls -l /mnt/fhpro`, I see the following output:

```
total 8192
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 131072 Jun 27 14:11 randomdir
```

Additionally, `ls /mnt -l` reveals that the mount point itself has also switched ownership to the `pi` user.

Furthermore, I can not write to the directory, as `touch /mnt/fhpro/test.txt` results in:

`touch: cannot touch '/mnt/fhpro/test.txt': Permission denied`

I am at a loss for what is going on here. I had a similar mount command set in my `/etc/fstab` before, and the drive would always mount with ownership set as expected. Now, that is no longer the case.

Any ideas?

Edit:

The man page for `mount.exfat` [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/mount.exfat.8.html) says:

> uid=n  Set  the  owner  for  all  files  and directories. The default is the owner of the current process.

I am running this command from the account that I would like to own the contents of the drive (i.e. **not** the `pi` user). So clearly something is up.

Comment: > My desired behavior is that the drive is able to be read and written to by members of a certain group.

Comment: Then why does the man page describe an option to set the owner for all files and directories? I am not asking for file-level permissions. I want the drive as a whole to be rwx for a specific group, which requires setting the owner of the mount itself to that group...

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the issue. The drive was automatically being mounted to `/media/pi/fhpro`, under the `pi` user.

Unmounting the drive allowed me to remount at the desired location with the specified options, leading to the expected behavior.